# random function in Visual C++ is not random

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have this dieRole function on Mac but when I move it to Visual C++ 2012 the result will be 6 every time

```
int dieRoll() // return a number between 1 and 6
{
    static int maxRange = RAND_MAX / 6 * 6; 

    int result;
    do
    {
        result = rand();
    }
    while(result > maxRange);    
    return result % 6 + 1;       
}
```

Comment: [Don't use `rand`. It sucks.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: Consider using the C+11 <random> header instead with it's excellent machinery for better random distributions than the old C 'rand' function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider calling `srand()`. You can provide a different seed using the time or process id. Keep in mind that this is pseudo-randomness and not necessarily what you may consider 'random'.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    std::cout << dieRoll() << std::endl;
}
```

Try code above will yield different results every second or so. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize the pseudo random generator without that only the same numbers will be returned. You need to call srand() e.g. with the current time.